# On a cartesian description of the null space of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Given a matrix A, I was taught that to find a cartesian description of the null space of the matrix, we would find the basis of the row space (which is the transpose of the rows with leading ones in the row reduced form of A) and since this basis is orthogonal to the null space, we would take the transposed basis and hence a cartesian description is obtained.

However, wouldn't the rows of the original matrix A also provide a cartesian description of the null space (albeit with redundant equations)? Since the argument works not just for row reduced but for the original matrix as well. Is my understanding correct here?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by a "cartesian description." Those words are [not standard terminology](https://www.google.com/search?q=cartesian+description+of+the+null+space&oq=cartesian+description+of+the+null+space) in linear algebra. Thus you should provide a definition.

Comment: Unfortunately this is just the terminology my course uses. I'm not too sure what an exact definition of this would be, but as far as I can tell it is just the simple description of a space using the cartesian coordinates (e.g., ax + by = c for R2). Often this is compared with the parametric form, which defines the space using vectors and free parameters instead.

Comment: So, by “Cartesian description” of the null space do you mean a system of linear equations with the null space of $A$ as its solution?

Comment: Yes, to clarify, the null space would be the set of solution of the homogenous system of linear equation.